# Exact Time Ago is not coming form moment js

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am doing my project in reactjs and i want time ago to show in table.i am using moment js to show time ago(fromNow()) but it shows the time few second only when the data comes from server.And it shows directly 6hrs ago if the data are not coming from server.Eg afer 2minutes of time interval it shows 6 hours ago.As shown in table below.[image: table to shoe time ago]

the code of my project is shown below

```
componentDidMount() {
 let socket = new WebSocket('wss://api.example.com.np/ws');
 this.setState({ socket: socket,noOfVehicle:this.state.supportInfo.length });
 this.getSupportInfo();
 socket.onmessage = ((message) => {
   let socketData = JSON.parse(message.data);
   let device_id = socketData[0].device_id;
   let updatedSupportInfo = this.getUpdatedInfo(this.state.sourceName);
   let flag = true;
   let uSupport = updatedSupportInfo.map(function(item){
    if(device_id == item.device_id){
      item.current_pos = socketData[0].current_pos;
      if(item.current_pos){
        flag = true;
      item["latlng"] = item.current_pos.x + ',' + item.current_pos.y;
      }else{
        flag = false;
      }
     let time = new Date(socketData[0].timestamp);
     let now = new Date();    
      let timeAgoIn = moment(time).fromNow(true);
      item["timeAgoIn"] = timeAgoIn;
      }

 getSupportInfo() {
axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://support.taranga.com.np/support_info'
      })
    .then((response) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          if(response.data[i].current_pos){
            response.data[i]["latlng"] = response.data[i].current_pos.x + ',' + response.data[i].current_pos.y;
            let time = new Date(response.data[i].timestamp)
            let now = new Date();
             let a = moment(time);
             let b = moment(now);
            let timeAgo = b.diff(a, 'hours')
            let timeAgoIn = moment(time).fromNow(true)
            response.data[i]["timeAgo"] = timeAgo;
            response.data[i]["timeAgoIn"] = timeAgoIn;
 }
        }
        this.setState({
        supportInfo: response.data
        });
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      throw (error);
    });
}

 getUpdatedInfo(name) {
    let uInfo = [];
    let tempSupport = this.state.supportInfo.slice();
    _.map(tempSupport,(value,key) =>{
      if(value.timeAgo !=0){
        let time = new Date(value.timestamp)
        let now = new Date();
        let a = moment(time);
        let b = moment(now);
        let timeAgo = b.diff(a, 'minutes')
        console.log(timeAgo);
        //let timeAgo = moment.duration(b-a).humanize()
        let timeAgoIn = moment(time).fromNow(true)
        value["timeAgo"] = timeAgo;
        value["timeAgoIn"] = timeAgoIn;
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      supportInfo:tempSupport
    });
```

the code to show in table is

```
 <TableHeaderColumn dataField="timeAgoIn" dataSort={true}>Time Ago</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: why you are using `new Date()` for `timestamp` from server? Is it required there? And what is the format of `timestamp`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your logic is flawed, when you get the info you are storing the timeAgo once, however timeAgo is a property that changes over time, ex:

You receive a message at 12:00, you set timeAgo to 1 second (or w/e js sets it to)
You check your screen at 12:05, timeAgo for that message is still 1 second, because this is calculated once, but time has passed and timeAgo should be 5 seconds ago, right?

timeAgo property should remain as the timestamp you received from server and be calculated when you refresh your table (when you want to do this is a different topic)

Comment: yes i have done what you have said. But nothing changed. Still the same problem.

Comment: first thing: I just realised this: `let uSupport = updatedSupportInfo.map(function(item){
    if(device_id == item.device_id)` this is not how you are supposed to use `map` use `find` instead. Second thing: please update your post with the code you are using to refresh the calculation of the time ago I cannot comment on code I cannot see